# SeekBar color bar does not match progress and thumb

Tags: android, seekbar, repaint, autorotate

When the screen rotates my seekbar's colored bar goes back to its initial value, while the thumb remains at the correct position.

Basically from this:

[image]

It becomes like this:

[image]

Note that the `TextView` showing `15` is connected to the seekbar and correctly shows the same value, which is updated in `onCreateView` retrieving the value with `getProgress` on the seekbar, so the seekbar *has* the correct progress internally but "forgets" to update its bar. Note also that if moved slightly, the bar will be updated correctly.

The strange thing is that I have an identical seekbar, on which I do exactly the same actions(method calls etc) but this one never has this problem.

They are defined in the same way in the XML layout file(except for the `id`).

These seekbars are inside a `Fragment` shown into a `ViewPager`, here's more or less the code for the fragment:

```
public class NewCharacterNameFragment extends Fragment
        implements NumericSeekBar.OnValueChangedListener {

    private static final String LEVEL = "org.my.package.LEVEL";
    private static final String STATS = "org.my.package.STATS";

    private NumericSeekBar levelBar;   // Causing problems
    private NumericSeekBar statsBar;   // Well behaved

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {  // defaults values to avoid multiple checks later
            savedInstanceState = new Bundle();
            savedInstanceState.putInt(LEVEL, 1);
            savedInstanceState.putInt(STATS, 30);
        }

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_character_name_fragment, container,
                                     false);

        levelBar = (NumericSeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.levelSeekBar);
        statsBar = (NumericSeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.statPointsSeekBar);

        levelBar.setValue(savedInstanceState.getInt(LEVEL));
        levelBar.setMax(20);
        levelBar.setValueChangedListener(this);

        statsBar.setValue(savedInstanceState.getInt(STATS));
        statsBar.setMax(100);
        statsBar.setValueChangedListener(this);

        // Initialize the text-views with the progress values:
        TextView tView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.statPointsNumTextView);
        tView.setText(Integer.valueOf(statsBar.getValue()).toString());
        tView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.levelNumTextView);
        tView.setText(Integer.valueOf(levelBar.getValue()).toString());

        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        savedInstanceState.putInt(LEVEL, levelBar.getValue());
        savedInstanceState.putInt(STATS, statsBar.getValue());
    }


    @Override
    public void onNumericSeekBarValueChanged(NumericSeekBar bar, int value,
                                             boolean fromUser) {
        // Called whenever the seekbar value changes
        if (bar == statsBar) {
            TextView view = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.statPointsNumTextView);
            view.setText(Integer.valueOf(value).toString());
        } else if (bar == levelBar) {
            TextView view = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.levelNumTextView);
            view.setText(Integer.valueOf(value).toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Where `NumericSeekBar` is a widget I created and is basically a `LinearLayout` with the two increment and decrement buttons and the seekbar:

```
public class NumericSeekBar extends LinearLayout
        implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener, View.OnClickListener {


    public interface OnValueChangedListener {
        public void onNumericSeekBarValueChanged(NumericSeekBar bar, int value,
                                                 boolean fromUser);
    }

    private Button incButton;
    private Button decButton;
    private SeekBar seekBar;

    private OnValueChangedListener listener = null;

    private int maxValue = 100;
    private int value = 0;


    public NumericSeekBar(Context ctx) {
        super(ctx);
        setOpts();
        setWidgets();
    }

    public NumericSeekBar(Context ctx, AttributeSet attributes) {
        super(ctx, attributes);
        setOpts();
        setWidgets();
    }

    public void setValueChangedListener(OnValueChangedListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public void setMax(int maxValue) {
        this.maxValue = maxValue;
        seekBar.setMax(maxValue);
    }


    public int getValue() {
        return this.value;  // using seekBar.getProgress() obtains same results
    }

    public boolean setValue(int value) {
        if (value < 0 || value > maxValue) {
            return false;
        }
        this.value = value;
        seekBar.setProgress(value);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar bar) {
        bar.setSecondaryProgress(bar.getProgress());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar bar) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar bar, int value, boolean fromUser) {
        this.value = value;
        if (listener != null ){
            listener.onNumericSeekBarValueChanged(this, value, fromUser);
        }

        if (!fromUser) {
            bar.setSecondaryProgress(0);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Handle increment/decrement button clicks
        if (v.equals(incButton)) {
            this.setValue(this.getValue() + 1);
        } else if(v.equals(decButton)) {
            this.setValue(this.getValue() - 1);
        }
    }


    private void setOpts() {
        setOrientation(HORIZONTAL);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            setShowDividers(SHOW_DIVIDER_NONE);
        }
    }

    private void setWidgets() {
        incButton = new Button(getContext());
        decButton = new Button(getContext());
        seekBar = new SeekBar(getContext());

        incButton.setText("+");
        incButton.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 16);
        incButton.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                                   ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                                   (float) 0.4));
        incButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        decButton.setText("-");
        decButton.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 16);
        decButton.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                                   ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                                   (float) 0.4));

        decButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                                     ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                                     (float) 0.2);
        layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

        seekBar.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        setMax(this.maxValue);
        setValue(this.value);


        addView(incButton);
        addView(seekBar);
        addView(decButton);

        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    }
}
```

This happens both on the emulator and on a physical device.

**EDIT:** I just tested my app on an android 4 emulator and this does not happen, so it seems to be something 2.x related.

**EDIT2:** I've tried to `invalidate()` the bars in `onCreateView`, `onStart` and `onResume` but the problems still occurs. I've also tried to put a `levelBar.setValue(levelBar.getValue())` in `onResume` but nothing changed.
I really don't understand what's happening.

**EDIT3:** I've added an other fragment which contains six of these bars and only the `levelBar` in the code above behaves strangely. I wonder how is this possible. Either there is some really strange bug, or I'm doing something not properly, even though I can't see where(and in android 4.x all works well).

**EDIT4:** My third edit is incorrect: now *almost* all the bars have this behaviour. The `statsBar` above seems to be the only one that is never affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally understood what's wrong with the code.

It seems like changing the maximum value of a `SeekBar` does **not** trigger a repaint of the color bar while it does trigger a repaint of the thumb. This is probably a bug in android 2.x(since it does not happen in android 4.x).

To solve this problem you simply have to set the maximum value *before* setting the progress on the seek-bar.

In my case only some bars were affected because I set the default maximum for the `NumericSeekBar` to 100, and only the bars with a different maximum where affected.

It's still not clear why invalidating the view in `onResume` does not produce the correct re-drawn of the widget.

Answer (score 0):

I find the recurrence method:

```
final SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.test_seekbar);
seekBar.setMax(4000);
seekBar.setProgress(1500);
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        seekBar.setProgress(500);
    }
}).start();
for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
    seekBar.setProgress(2000);
}
```

above code, called `ProgressBar#setProgress` in work thread, it causes the bug.
Android official documentation advice called it at main thread, like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
private static final int PROGRESS = 0x1;

private ProgressBar mProgress;
private int mProgressStatus = 0;

private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    setContentView(R.layout.progressbar_activity);

    mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

    // Start lengthy operation in a background thread
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (mProgressStatus < 100) {
                mProgressStatus = doWork();

                // Update the progress bar
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        mProgress.setProgress(mProgressStatus);
                    }
                });               
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
}
```